# Build failure: invalid task on maven

Tags: maven, jenkins

Currently I'm reading the 'Jenkins Continuous Integration Cookbook', which I'm following the instructions for. After running the command:

```
mvn clean integration-test –Dlog4j.configuration=file./src/test/
```

I get the error:

[INFO] Invalid task '–Dlog4j.configuration=file./src/test/': you must specify a valid lifecycle phase, or a goal in the format plugin:goal or pluginGroupId:pluginArtifactId:pluginVersion:goal

This is my log4j.properties file which is in /src/test/resources:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x -
%m%n
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your copy-paste is a little too good, and the text of the book you're using is badly formatted/encoded.

The problem is in the hyphen you're using, i.e.

`–`

This is [`EN_DASH`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm), which is **not** the normal hyphen character

`-`

**So the solution is to use the "normal" hyphen, `-`**, i.e.:

```
mvn clean integration-test -Dlog4j.configuration=file./src/test/
```

Also, as Funtik correctly points out, the general convention is for the JVM args to be input **before** the phases/goals.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this solved it. I'll be much more careful next time.

Comment: @user1413969 : you're welcome, and don't worry that you've missed it, those kind of problems are hard to pinpoint unless you're previously suspicious of them. For example, I've recently had "great fun" debugging an issue that turned out to be the presence U+00A0, i.e. *non-breaking space*, which looks like this: .

Answer (score 2):

try passing the arguments first

```
mvn –Dlog4j.configuration=file./src/test/ clean integration-test
```

from the `mvn --help`

```
usage: mvn [options] [<goal(s)>] [<phase(s)>]
```

Comment: Well, at least some versions of Maven do accept JVM params after the goal. The problem is somewhere else I'm afraid. Although of course you're right in general that this is the "proper" way.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong in that regard :). It's just that this is clearly a case of a wrong character being used. Try it yourself - copy OPs command into the command line. And see my answer for more info.